# Getting Twitter data in a web extension without remote scripts

Tags: twitter, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a WebExtension for Firefox. In order to post my extension, it must not have any remote scripts in it.

In order to display some tweets in my extension's menu, I have used the [Twitter-Post-Fetcher](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher) library, but I can't post my extension with it because the library uses remote scripts from twitter.com.

I prefer not to use the Twitter API if possible, because the requests would come from the extension's users.

Answer (score 0):

No remote scripts means that if you are going execute code in the context of your extension, then the code *must* be included in the extension package, not hosted on some server. While there may be other ways to accomplish this (e.g. running the code in the page context, which *may* be acceptable, but may not), the default way to accomplish this is to: **download the code that you are executing and use a copy that you include in the extension package**.

This is the case for **all** code, including libraries such as jQuery. It is *highly* recommended that the code be an *exact* byte-by-byte copy of code that can be downloaded from a public repository, and that you indicate within your extension package the exact URL you used to obtain the code.

The reason for this is security. If downloading code at runtime was permitted, then that code could be trivially changed at any time. It would mean that having the add-on reviewed by Mozilla would be of no benefit.

Please see the [Review Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/AMO/Policy/Reviews) page on MDN, and all the pages linked from there, for more details.

Comment: My question is not _what_ remote scripts are, but rather how to avoid using them in the context of Twitter.

Comment: @SilverTuxedo, My answer states that you should download those scripts and include them in your extension package. That is the normal way to solve this type of problem. If it does not solve your problem, please provide some explanation as to why you can not use that as a solution. I have put that part of the answer in bold to make it stand out a bit more.